# How to display JasperReports Viewer inside a JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jasper-reports

I'm a newbie in using JasperReports. In my Swing application I want to show JRViewer inside a JPanel. I know how to display JRViewer inside a JFrame but i'm having a hard time in displaying it in a JPanel.

Can anyone help me out?

I'd tried this code.

```
JRViewer jv = new JRViewer(jp);  
panel.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0)));
panel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1000, 700));
panel.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());
panel.add(jv);
panel.repaint();
panel.revalidate();
```

There's no error but the report did not appear in the jpanel.

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me

```
 JRViewer vw=new JRViewer(jp); 
       jPanel13.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
       jPanel13.repaint();
       jPanel13.add(vw);
       jPanel13.revalidate();
```

Answer (score -1):

What does JRViewer extend? What layout manager is the JPanel using? Make sure that it's using something that can expand the component to fill it such as a BorderLayout.

Edit:  JRViewer extends JPanel, so your problem boils down to simply showing one JPanel inside of another. Again, have the outer JPanel use a BorderLayout or other reasonable layout manager, and then simply add the JRViewer instance to it, then call `repaint()` and `revalidate()` on the container JPanel. You will also want to read the Swing tutorials on use of JPanels and the layout managers since this is all well explained there.

Comment: I’d tried this code but still it doesn’t work.

panel.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0)));
panel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1000, 700));
panel.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());
panel.add(jv);
panel.repaint();
panel.revalidate();

Comment: @user2322019: please post code as an edit to your original post. If code doesn't work, tell us the details of your problem. Just saying "doesn't work" gives us little to go on.